# Работа с параметрами приложения

Tags: c#

На данный момент параметр сохраняется так

```
Properties.Settings.Default.us_PathBD = value;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Возможно ли обращаться к параметру указав имя в виде строки?

Comment: Зачем? Что вы имеете ввиду под параметром? Если us_PathBD то это поле или свойство

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Properties.Settings.Default["us_PathBD"] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нет индексатора, как в предыдущем ответе, то можно задать поле с помощью отражений

```
 var info = typeof(MyClass).GetField("MyPropName");
 info.SetValue(typeof(MyClass), "PropValue");
```

для свойства, так же только нужно использовать метод

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(...);
```